# How to update values of each object in the array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array having multiple objects:

```
[ {col:1} {col:1} {col:1} {col:3} {col:3} {col:9} {col:12} {col:13} ]
```

I want to update this array such that col having values 1 will remain same while the next value  (here 3) should become 2 and then next value(here 9) should become 3 and so on..

O/P:

```
[ {col:1} {col:1} {col:1} {col:2} {col:2} {col:3} {col:4} {col:5} ]
```

Please help.

Comment: does final order matter? Also what have you tried? Will get far better response if you show an effort was made

Comment: Yes the final order does matter.I tried creating array of values and then change each value but it all gone mess.

Comment: Is the input array guaranteed to be sorted by `.col`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fairly simple method:

```js
var arr = [ {col:1}, {col:1}, {col:1}, {col:3}, {col:3}, {col:9}, {col:12}, {col:13} ];
var current = 0;
var prevEl = -1;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var el = arr[i].col;
    arr[i].col = el > prevEl ? ++current : current;
    prevEl = el;
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your array:

```
var data = [
    { col: 1 }, { col: 1 },
    { col: 1 }, { col: 3 },
    { col: 3 }, { col: 9 },
    { col: 12 }, { col: 13 }
];

var result = data.reduce(function(r, i) {
    r.previous !== i.col && r.newValue++;
    r.previous = i.col;
    r.arr.push({ col: r.newValue });
    return r;
}, {arr: [], newValue: 0}).arr;

console.log(result);
```

I suppose your array is sorted by `col`, otherwise you need to sort it first.

Answer (score 1):

Should do what is needed. Doesn't rely on any specific order in original array and assumes will always start at `1`

```js
var data=[ {col:1} ,{col:1} ,{col:1} ,{col:3} ,{col:3}, {col:9} ,{col:12} ,{col:13} ];

var uniqueValues = data.reduce(function(a,c){
   if(a.indexOf(c.col)===-1) {
      a.push(c.col);
   }  
   return a;
},[]).sort(function(a,b){
   return a-b;
}); // produces [1,3,9,12,13]

var res=data.map(function(item){
   // use index of current col value from unique values .. plus one
   item.col=uniqueValues.indexOf(item.col) + 1;
   return item;
});

document.getElementById('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res,null,4)
```

```html
<pre id="pre">
```

Edit: if lowest col isn't `1` can still use `uniqueValues.indexOf(item.col) + uniqueValues [0]`

Answer (score -1):

You could run a `for` loop to iterate through your array, and have if clauses to check for certain values; say the array object is called `myArray`:

```
var myArray = [ {col:1} {col:1} {col:1} {col:3} {col:3} {col:9} {col:12} {col:13} ];

for ( var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    if ( myArray[i] === 3 ){
        myArray[i] = 2;
    }
    // and so on.....
}
```

Comment: Why the down votes? It may not be 100% flexible, but for the situation I don't see the issue.

Comment: the input array may not be the same every time

Comment: `myArray[i]` is an object. Concept also doesn't adjust based on filling holes in values and is definitely not scalable. Create your own demo will see problems appear then